# Ethernet USB Adapter Not Working

Tags: usb, internet, ethernet, adapter

I have **usb ethernet adapter HP RJ45** and have dual-boot OS setup Win10/ **Ubuntu 18.04.1** on my Microsoft Surface Book. Under Win10 it works, but not under Ubuntu.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
ifconfig -a                       
enx9cebe885a0b9: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:eb:e8:85:a0:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9053532  bytes 1466227710 (1.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9053532  bytes 1466227710 (1.4 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.34  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c0e3:30bb:e75f:2333  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:5f:d3:52:18:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2349371  bytes 2260752246 (2.2 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 432672  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1318692  bytes 229615901 (229.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 98:5f:d3:52:18:82
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mwifiex_pcie ip=192.168.1.34 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:b9500000-b95fffff memory:b9400000-b94fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx9cebe885a0b9
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:85:a0:b9
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

In Settings > Network it says that the cable is unplugged, although it is not:

[Cable unplugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggXKk.png)

Comment: Please describe your network wiring from the RJ adapter on the dongle, all the way to the router/modem.